# Custom button to add existing records

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-button

I am trying to add a custom button to add existing records to a custom object related list (Specifications(custom obj) to Products(custom obj))

Ext class code:

```
public with sharing class AddExistingSpecsExt {

    public Product__c specs  { get; set; }

    public AddExistingSpecsExt() {

        String specs Specification__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        specs = [SELECT Id, Name, Product__c FROM specs WHERE Id =: specs.Id];

    }

    public PageReference associate () {

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity ( Id = Specification__c.Product__c, specsid = Specification__c.Id);

        try {
            Database.update(opp);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error while associating.' + error.getMessage()));
        }

        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + specs.Id);

        return page.setRedirect(true);
    }

    public PageReference cancel () {
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + specs.Id);
        return page.setRedirect(true);        
    }

}
```

I am getting this error:

> Line 7: expecting a semi-colon, found 'Specification__c'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the word `Specification__c`. You have declared your variable name twice.

The syntax for variable declaration is:

```
Type | variableName | [=value]
```

Here you have:

```
Type | variableName | variableName | =value
```

A more proper constructor would be:

```
public Specification__c loadedSpec { get; private set; }

public AddExistingSpecsExt() {
    String specId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    if (String.isBlank(specId)) return;

    List<Specification__c> candidates = [
        SELECT Id, Name, Product__c FROM Specification__c WHERE Id = :specId LIMIT 1
    ];
    if (!candidates.isEmpty()) loadedSpec = candidates[0];
}
```

Comment: That gives me this error. Already tried it :(   sObject type 'specs' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: @Jason Look at my recommendation for how to set up your constructor. Also your `SOQL` needs to have a `FROM` clause that uses the proper `API Name` of an object in your org.

Comment: @Jason Any luck? Further errors?

Comment: I am receiving the following error, I have posted the new code above. : Invalid initial expression type for field Specifications__c.Id, expecting: Id Line 16

Comment: @Jason That is a completely different question. You should accept this answer, remove that code from your question here, and ask it separately. It is really hard to track what is going on if you continually overhaul the OP. Especially because you are now running into a completely different core issue.

Comment: accepted and asked a new question